# vue.js dynamic router link wrap with image tag

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I am building a blog with vue.js and I am trying to make my image clickable and after clicking the image it will direct to one of my vue components.
I got stuck on passing the query string dynamically(the query string is the blog content id retrieve from MongoDB and the image work as a thumbnail for the blog post.)

so far I've tried

```
<router-link to="/blogcontent/:${post.bcid}" tag="img" v-bind:src="`/static/uploads/` + post.thumbnail"></router-link>
```

and

```
<router-link to="{ name: 'BlogContent', params: { blogId: post.bcid }" tag="img" v-bind:src="`/static/uploads/` + post.thumbnail"></router-link>
```

but none of them works.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have syntax errors in your `router-link` tag.  When you pass any javascript in your attribute, you need to use `v-bind` or `:`. For example, in your router-link, you used `to="{ name: ...}"`, you should update the `to` attribute to `:to`, take note of the colon before the `to` tag.

Second, `router-link` renders an anchor tag, what you can do is you can have a separate `img` tag and wrap it with the router-link.  Something like this:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'blogcontent', params: {blogId: post.bcid} }">
  <img :src="post.thumbnail" />
</router-link>
```

I have created a simple fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/iamriel/waarpq0s/1/